# Object sqli insert from $_SESSION

Tags: php, object, mysqli, foreach, insert

I need some help coding this.
I want to insert each $value element from $_SESSION into $key coloumn(these were created after $key). Something like

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    // "INSERT INTO test (".$value.") VALUES (". $key.")";
}
```

i was looking at [Best way to INSERT many values in mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli)
but i dont quite get it
Since im useing mysqli it has to be objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the general idea. Try this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO test (".$value.") VALUES (".$key.")";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

And that should be it. This will loop through each item, then it will define and execute a query. Pretty simple.

Comment: Ok this works, but each insert goes into new row, meaning there is only 1 piece of data filled in in each row

Comment: Well yes, it would do that. Look at your insert statement. You only send 1 value (aka 1 column) to the database. You would need to change it to an `INSERT INTO test (column, column, column, etc...) VALUES (value, value, value, etc...)`

Comment: It is open door for poor performance and sql injections. you should use prepared statements to insert in batch