# PHP array to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a output

```
Array( 
    [0] => user ip ex XX.XX.XXX.X
    [1] => XXX.XXX.XXX.X
   )
   [6525] => XXX.XX.X.XXX
  )
]
```

I must add all value to MySQL my code is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ipdata (ip)
VALUES ('$array[]')"
```

Please help i must add all for database

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli).

Comment: You have mismatched brackets in your array.