# PHP/MySQL data migration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch 5100 rows from a MySQL database to another. However, it seems that the script only fetches around 1300 and ends.

The script has two connections, one for each db. The code looks like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con_remote,"SELECT * FROM product_images");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    //Insert
    mysqli_query($con_local,"INSERT INTO product_images (id, filename, 
product_id) VALUES('$row[product_image_id]', '$row[product_image_filename]', 
'$row[fk_product_id]')");
}
```

I have also added `ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);` at the start of the script in order to avoid execution timeout. What could I improve/change to get all 5100 rows?

Edit: I ended up with exporting the remote database and import it to my local machine and then change the column names.

Comment: Do you have the option to use mysql on command line?

Comment: @WKoppel, I'm not great at using the command line. That's why I made the php script to execute on my local apache.

Comment: Read about `mysqldump` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: @Frederik well if you want to be a developer I suggest you lose that mindset that you don't wanna do something because you don't feel comfortable doing it. Learn it, doing simpler things like dumping an table from database and importing to another it isn't that hard. With CLI you can do it under a minute.

Comment: @WKoppel, you are completely right about that.

Comment: You need to insert row using batch insert. So use `TRANSACTION` for it. Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli

Comment: "I have also added ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);" Your PHP is most likely out of memory.. Make it a habit  out of it to  **always** program code with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true)` then you would 95-97% of the PHP errors/notices/warnings.. Some PHP functions like `mysqli_query` does not trigger a error you need to use `mysqli_error()` to see it..

Comment: @Frederik When I started with PHP few years ago I always didn't want to do things that seemed hard, but after completing my task I always felt that it was me that's trying to make look things hard or impossible. Good luck!

Comment: His best and most easy option by the way @hardiksolanki would be to use `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM table...`

Comment: Yeah @RaymondNijland, He should use `multi_query` as well.

Comment: if `multi_query` is the answer you are asking the wrong question @hardiksolanki let me explain that `multi_query` is "dangerours" because you can't use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections and we al know `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not that great to prevent SQL injections.. And because `multi_query` support queries separated with semicon `;` where `mysqli_query` or `mysqli_prepare` does not it's also possible to inject `1; DROP TABLE table` for example

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I agreed. Thanks for explanation. :)

Comment: No problem.. Besides `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM table...` is one query which can be executed just fine with `mysqli_query` @hardiksolanki

Comment: @RaymondNijland INSERT/SELECT won't work because he has not only two different databases but two different hosts.

Comment: Your are right @DanFromGermany just noticed he is using two seperated connections i geuss i need some more coffee.. Want if he going to use a extra [FEDERATED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) table to get the data from local to the remote server then he could use the INSERT/SELECT query like i said.. Iám pretty sure `FEDERATED` table engine is enabled by default on a windows MySQL version but i  assume here the topicstarter is using windows on his local machine..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I use Windows 10 in my local machine, yes :).

Comment: Ok check `SHOW ENGINES` to see if `FEDERATED` is here then you can use the documentation to get it started..

Answer (score 1):

Please try below this should work. Refer attached code.
This is simple no need to retrieve while or for loop

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'db1');

// Create connection for second db
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully for Second";
mysqli_select_db($conn2, 'db2');
echo '<br>';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO db1.table1 (ID, NAME) 
SELECT ID, NAME FROM db2.table1';

if (mysqli_query($conn2, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn2);
}
mysqli_close($conn2);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

insert this php function in above your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
set_time_limit(int $seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set script execution time to zero, means the script can run forever. Add the following at the start of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```