# How Fast data insert in db table through Corn with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1,00,000 record in my table A and I need some data of A insert B table through Corn with some other data. So In implement below code and set pagination rule but every new page it taking time.

Every 10000 record (it's a page limit) page change and it's increase process time. how to reduse process time.

```
$DB = new myclassi();

$resource_new = "SELECT COUNT(`gi`.`igems_item_id`) as total 
FROM `gems_item` AS `gi` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `gicd`.`id` FROM `gems_item_cron_data` As `gicd` WHERE `gi`.`old_sku` = `gicd`.`gems_old_sku` AND `gi`.`igems_item_id` = `gicd`.`gems_itemid`)
AND `gi`.`diamond_video_url` IS NOT NULL 
AND (`gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%http%' OR  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%https%')";
$res = $DB->select_assoc($resource_new);
$total_rows = $res[0]['total'];


$no_of_records_per_page = 10000;
$total_pages  =  ceil ($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
$limit = "";
$pageno = 1;
 

for($i=0;$i < $total_pages; $i++){
    
    $offset = ($pageno) * $no_of_records_per_page;
    if ($pageno > 1) {
        $prev_offset = ($offset - $no_of_records_per_page) + 1;
        $limit = $prev_offset.", ".$no_of_records_per_page;
    }else{
        $limit = "0, ".$no_of_records_per_page;
    }
    
    $sqlr="SELECT `gi`.`igems_item_id`, `gi`.`old_sku`, `gi`.`diamond_video_url` 
    FROM `gems_item` AS `gi` 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `gicd`.`id` FROM `gems_item_cron_data` As `gicd` WHERE `gi`.`old_sku` = `gicd`.`gems_old_sku` AND `gi`.`igems_item_id` = `gicd`.`gems_itemid`)
    AND  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` IS NOT NULL 
    AND (`gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%http%' OR  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%https%')  LIMIT ". $limit;
    $results = $DB->select_assoc($sqlr);                    
    if (isset($results) && !empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $url = urldecode($row['diamond_video_url']);
            $k = $row['igems_item_id'];
            $video_url = 'xxxfdafas';
            $old_sku = $row['old_sku'];
            $diamond_video_url = $row['diamond_video_url'];
            $diamond_final_video_url = urlencode($video_url);
            $is_url_found = '';
            $is_processed = 0;
            $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $sql = "INSERT INTO gems_item_cron_data (`gems_itemid`,`gems_old_sku`, `diamond_final_video_url`,`is_processed`,`created_at`) 
            VALUES ($k, '$old_sku','$diamond_final_video_url', '$is_processed', '$created_at')";
            $DB->insert($sql);
        }
    }
    $pageno++;
}
$DB->close();
```

Please let me know how to make faster insert process.

Comment: By "corn", do you mean "cron"?

Comment: [MySQL supports a single statement with multiple rows to INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502067/231316). [Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149622/231316) are also an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplify test**

This

```
      AND  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` IS NOT NULL
      AND  (`gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%http%'
              OR  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE '%https%'
           )";
```

can be simplified, and sped up significantly, to this

```
     AND  `gi`.`diamond_video_url` LIKE 'http%'
```

especially if the URL necessarily *starts with* "http".

**Eliminate COUNT**

I suggest there is no need to first count the rows.  Simply do the `SELECT` to fetch the rows, then notice whether you got any rows.  That, alone, will (probably) more than double the speed of the program.

**Batch INSERT**

If practical, replace the loop and single-row inserts with

```
INSERT INTO ... (...)
    SELECT ...
```

That might give another factor of 10 in speedup.

If the `SELECT` returns no rows, there will be nothing to `INSERT`.  Real cheap.

After you have done those, there may be further optimizations, but then I would need to see the new query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.